# кнопка radio добавление values

Tags: html

```
<div class="zone1_">
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="stol" id="stol-1" value="Stol_1">
    <label for="stol-1"><b>1</b></label>
</div>
<div class="zone1_">
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="stol" id="stol-2" value="Stol_2">
    <label for="stol-2"><b>1</b></label>
</div>
```

В базе есть поле `stol`
Как передавать ему значения `value="stol_1"`, `value="stol_2"`?

Сейас добавляется один раз, т.к `name="stol"` и всё.
То есть в форме есть поля время (сделано через `select`) и столы (сделано через `radio`). `select` нормально передаёт `values`, а как `radio` передавать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип `radio` - это группа объектов с возможностью выбора ТОЛЬКО ОДНОГО из группы. Т.е. если у вас несколько `radio` и все с `name="stol"`, то только одну из всех Вы сможете выбрать.
Вот [здесь](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/08/checked.html) можно почитать детально.

В зависимости от того, что у Вас за форма и как она должна работать, Вам имеет смысли либо сменить на `checkbox`, либо оформить `stol`, как select. Могут быть еще варианты - все зависит от Вашего задания.

Comment: ясно, буду селект разукрашивать) , спасибо.

Comment: а с помощью чекбокса как ?)

Comment: сначала объясните подробнее что за форма, сколько полей, что делает, и почему там несколько `stol`. будем думать :)

Comment: в формез 5 столов с именем "stol" нужно в базу заносить value= stol_1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что форма позволяет для какого-то действия (например, покер) выбрать один из 5-ти столов?

Comment: ага, бронирование стола в кальянной:)

Comment: ну если это бронирование стола, тогда все-таки `radio` это то, что Вам нужно. Т.е. форма позволяет выбрать один из пяти столов. Но тогда непонятно вот это из Вашего вопроса: `Сейас добавляется один раз, т.к name="stol" и всё.` А что еще надо-то? Вы передаете номер выбранного стола и все...

Comment: чтобы 500 раз не забронировали) проверяется дата и время и номер стола.

Comment: придётся в базу добавлять 10 столов и для каждого радио делать)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30270/discussion-between-cyadvert-and-).

Comment: то есть в один день на разное время надо. а в базу заносится "stol" и всё